# monitoring rx/tx stats of current connections on Linux

Tags: linux, iptables, linux-networking, network-monitoring

In a Linux netfilter router, connections table only includes information on end of connections. Where I reach real time rx/tx information for each connection? (In freebsd, session table already provides)

Thank you.

Comment: Can you work on improving your question?  It isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am replying my own question:

The answer is conntrack accounting.

sysctl -w net.netfilter.nf_conntrack_acct=1

tcp      6 299 ESTABLISHED src=144.111.111.11 dst=192.168.1.2
sport=35042 dport=22 packets=585 bytes=41244 src=192.168.1.2
dst=144.111.111.11 sport=22 dport=35042 packets=423 bytes=195796
[ASSURED] mark=0 use=2

Thank you,

Comment: What command did you use to get the "tcp 6 299 ESTABLISHED..." output?

Comment: sudo conntrack -L